# Editing a global dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I know this question has been tossed around much but still it's not very clear to me.
I have a file 'vmsupport.py'. Among it's many functions, it has one in particular where it needs to add a new element to a global dictionary 'netpathdict'.I have declared

```
netpathdict={}
```

at the start of the script because I want to use this dictionary in another function in an another file 'core.py'. Contents of the vmsupport.py file:

```
  storefile="%s/netsummary_%s.html" % (full_paths[1].rsplit('/',1)[0],build)
  netpathdict[build] = storefile
  self.logger.debug("storefile at %s key of dictionary is %s" %(build,netpathdict[build]))
```

contents of 'core.py' file:

```
def view_networksummary(request,build):
 result_file= netpathdict[build]
 f = open(result_file,'r')
 return HttpResponse(f)
 f.close()
```

So, my question is, how exactly do I import the dictionary to core.py and use it and how would I be sure that the dictionary in use is the edited one.(Actually the vmsupport.py file works on a daemon that continuously adds elements to the dictionary. Hence, it's NOT a one time affair )
Thank you

Comment: I don't think `global netpathdict[build] = storefile` is valid Python.  Does this code work at all?

Comment: ^ yes, I looked into it. I changed it to: 'netpathdict[build] = storefile'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how exactly do I import the dictionary to core.py and use it and how would I be sure that the dictionary in use is the edited one.

You don't. You import the containing module and mutate the object contained in the attribute.

```
import foo
foo.bar.append('baz')
```

Comment: ^ but the dictionary has been declared globally and has been edited in a function 'def foo'. So, you are saying importing the function 'def foo' into core.py will give me an up-to date version of the dictionary (As i had pointed out before, dictionary is being continuously edited by a daemon ) ?

Comment: If the dictionary has been declared globally then why would you care about the function?

Comment: Okay, so if I have declared it globally and am editing it in any function, it will be edited globally. Hence, I can use it wherever I want to. Is that what you are trying to say?

Comment: As long as you don't rebind the name, it will remain the same object.